# Nome do Servidor MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, odbc

Estou acompanhando uma vídeo aula na qual a instrutora coloca o nome do seu servidor no ODBC conforme consta no mysql, porém como a minha versão (MySQL Workbench 8.0.15) é diferente e não consta o nome. Gostaria de saber como descubro.
[image: Nesta Imagem no canto inferior da esquerda conta dentro da "Pesquisador do Objeto" o no do servidor "MAQLAB-PC"]

[image: Na minha versão não consigo encontrar]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você deve abrir a linha de comandos do Windows (teclas Windows + R) e digitar `cmd`. Na janela que abrir, digite `hostname` e aperte enter. Na linha seguinte estará o nome da sua máquina.

Na aba do Workbench note que está escrito `local instance`. Isso significa que você está conectado à uma instância local (na própria máquina). Logo, você pode utilizar `localhost` como hostname, o que fará com que o MySQL se conecte ao servidor que está sendo executado em seu computador.

Comment: Olá, boa noite!, tentei seguir suas orientações mas continua dando erro.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.